# If the universe is flat, how can the Earth be round?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, physics, space

Just another silly question that may deserve a wise answer.

Comment: it's more of a science question?

Comment: This might be best in the Physics SE.

Comment: @FrankHubeny I don't think they would like it either

Comment: @JohnDvorak I don't think they would either, so I attempted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe) a flat universe would have this property:

> Zero curvature (flat); a drawn triangle's angles add up to 180° and the Pythagorean theorem holds...

This is not the case for the round Earth which has positive curvature on its surface:

> Positive curvature; a drawn triangle's angles add up to more than 180°...

The spherical objects in the universe may make it appear bumpy from a local perspective. From a more global perspective one would view the universe as flat having zero curvature even though those spherical objects within the universe have positive curvature.

---

"Shape of the universe" Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar question: if this sheet of paper is flat, can the circle drawn on it be round? And the answer is yes. Of course.

Answer (score 1):

Flatness or non-flatness of the universe is an issue concerning the large scale structure of the universe, more precisely a question about the curvature of spacetime.

Roundness of the earth and of other cosmic bodies is a local phenomenon due to the gravity of rotating bodies.